# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show notification but unfortunately i am getting error if work permit table has not record how can i resolve this issue ? thnaks.

**Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/zubair/htdocs/permit-to-work/cms/resources/views/cms/layouts/header.blade.php)**

**view blade**

```
   @php
    $notifications = getNotication();
    @endphp
    @foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    <div class="notification-load">
    <a href="{{route('work.permit.edit',$notification->workPermit->id)}}" class="dropdown-item notify-item ">
    <div class="notify-icon bg-blue">
        <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white">
        </i>
    </div>
    @php
    $date=$notification->workPermit->validty_to;
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $validty_date = date("d,M ,Y", $timestamp);
    @endphp
    <p class="text-muted mb-0 user-msg ">
    <b>
    <small class="notification_list">Permit No {{$notification->workPermit->permit_code}}  validity is about to end at {{$validty_date}}
    </small>
    </b>
    </p>
    </a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Can you send what is `$notification` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

use this helper function

```
optional($notification->workPermit)->id
```

instead of that

```
$notification->workPermit
```